# Upload files to S3 during deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I want to create a bucket during the deployment process, but when I do this, a problem with assets appears, "must have values". So I decide to create a different stack to only upload files and other stack to deploy a EC2 instance. So, when I use this approach, the EC2.UserData didn't find the files on S3 to download them. I need this file to configure my instance. I could create the S3 manually before to deploy the EC2, but I want do automatize this process. How I could do this?

Comment: Can you share the code you've attempted with?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure S3 access at the machine where you wish to automate the process.

- Use AWS CLI tools and run [aws configure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) on your server and define the credentials.

OR

- If it is an EC2 instance then create [IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) with S3 write
  permissions and [attach to this EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/assign-iam-role-ec2-instance/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Create 2 separate stacks (we'll refer to them as `s3Stack` and `ec2Stack`)
2. Add `ec2Stack.addDependency(s3Stack)` where you create these stacks
3. In the s3 stack, create the bucket and upload the assets using [aws-s3-deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-s3-deployment-readme.html)
4. Give permissions to the ec2 instance to get necessary files from the previously created bucket.

This will ensure you can deploy everything with just one command `cdk deploy ec2Stack`. It will check if the s3Stack needs to be created/updated first and only when those updates are done, your ec2Stack will be deployed.